# Windows Username maximum length

Tags: windows, authentication

What is the maximum length of a Windows domain + username? That is, what is the legal limit for a  domain/username in Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read this

for windows 2000: http://technet.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb726984(en-us).aspx

for windows 2003: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783323.aspx

> ### Rules for Logon Names
>
> Logon names must follow these rules:
>
> - Local logon names must be unique on a workstation and global logon names must be unique throughout a domain.
> - Logon names **can be up to 104 characters**. However, it isn't practical to use logon names that are longer than 64 characters.
> - A Microsoft Windows NT version 4.0 or earlier logon name is given to all accounts, which by default is set to the first 20 characters of the Windows 2000 logon name. The Windows NT version 4.0 or earlier logon name must be unique throughout a domain.
> - Users logging on to the domain from Windows 2000 computers can use their Windows 2000 logon name or their Windows NT version 4.0 or earlier logon name, regardless of the domain operations mode.

Comment: for 2000 - up to 104, for 2003, up to 20 (plus domain)

Comment: Can you summarize your answer from the links and use them for additional reference?

Answer (score 34):

The maximum lengths are hash defined in [lmcons.h](http://doc.ddart.net/msdn/header/include/lmcons.h.html).  DNLEN is the maximum domain length and UNLEN is the maximum user name length.

In the version of this file I have on my XP machine (installed as part of Visual Studio 8), DNLEN = 15 and UNLEN = 256.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. The maximum path length is 259, for example the user Desktop folder on an English system is `C:\Users\[User]\Desktop` which leaves at most 241 characters for the user name. I suppose they could trim it but then they have to handle collisions etc. and I doubt they go to all that trouble. This ServerFault answer states 104 characters which sounds more reasonable: http://serverfault.com/a/105165

Comment: 256 is def. wrong. From http://technet.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb726984(en-us).aspx -> Logon names can be up to 104 characters. However, it isn't practical to use logon names that are longer than 64 characters.

Comment: @BerndOtt Thats Windows 2000 (from Chapter 8, Microsoft Windows 2000 Administrator's Pocket Consultant by William R. Stanek.)

Comment: @OhadSchneider The max path length will be dropped with Windows 10

Comment: @DanielFisherlennybacon it is, but you have to [opt in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx#maxpath) to get the new behavior.

Answer (score 2):

There is a constant UNLEN which is defined in Lmcons.h that defines the maximum length of a username

Answer (score 1):

compmgmt.msc allows usernames for local account at max with 20 characters.
dsa.msc allows domain user names to be 256.