# Storing windows login in SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, authentication, types

Are there any best practices for storing Windows logins in SQL server tables(e.g. AddUser field for an audit table)?  I have seen tables using sysname, varchar(255) etc.

p.s. Apologies in advance if this has already been answered. I couldn't find or formulate the right query to look this up.

Comment: Are you asking what's the max length of a username on windows or ... what's your use case?

Comment: I know that SQL server's built-in function suser_sname() returns nvarchar(256). My question was - what do people typically use?  I actually just found the answer when I googled suser_sname.  MSDN has an example where they are using sysname for storing login. Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved successfully? Do you still need help with this?

Answer (score 7):

Have you considered storing the user [SID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Identifier)?

Comment: SID would be more appropriate. It does not change even if the user is renamed. You can see such SID sometime when a user is deleted and you check the permission on a file. See http://kb.iu.edu/data/aotl.html

Comment: Makes sense, although I have never seen it used. What data type would that be? Would I have to write dog slow Active directory code to map it to something readable?

Comment: Here's a sample SID: `S-1-5-21-7623811015-3361044348-030300820-1013`
The format is well defined on WP http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Identifier and yes, it's going to come from the system or the AD, but honestly, this is probably not what you want...

Comment: SUSER_SNAME() can be used to transform a SID into a user name. It *does* go to AD when invoked, so it can be slow (although it caches the response). There still are some gotchas: if you move the database to a different domain, all SIDs become opaque (can't resolve them to name), accounts that are terminated may also become opaque, and SQL logins have 'valid' SIDs of their own, some that have a valid SID format but different authority (6) from Windows's (5), some that are just plain funny as a SID format (0x01, which is 'sa' SID). Some tools may expect a Windows SID only.

Answer (score 1):

Does this answer your question: [Windows Username maximum length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704891/windows-username-maximim-length) ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know of an accepted standard, typically I'll see them stored as varchar(255) though in systems I have worked on.